# Get back an Object List from a Spring controller to a AJAX request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I want to return a List of object from a Spring controller to an AJAX request.

**AJAX request:**

```
function doAjaxPost(date) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "<%="/water-consumer" + homepageURL + "/hourConsumption"%>",
        data : date,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response) {
            if(response != null)
                showHourConsumption(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**Spring controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/hourConsumption", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<HourConsumption> getHoursConsumptions(@RequestBody String day, HttpSession session, Model model) {
    // do something ....
    Household household = (Household)session.getAttribute("household");
    List<HourConsumption> consumptions = this.mrs.getHoursConsumption(household.getSmart_meter().getOid(), day);
    // do something 

    if(consumptions == null) //check if what get back from something is not null
        return null;
    else
        return consumptions; 
}
```

Now, the AJAX request goes right, so I receive the request from the controller and it generates the correct *consumptions (List)* but when it returns the List, the browser gives me back the following **error**:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406
>   (Not Acceptable)

Someone could tell me how can I do this things or the correct way to do so?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

1. The http method can be a GET iso a POST.
2. Remove session and model parameters. If you need session then you can obtain it from an Autowired `HttpServletRequest`.
3. Make sure you have Jackson as dependency

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that following 2 jar's are present in class path.

If any one or both are missing then this error will come.

jackson-core and jackson-mapper

Comment: What are the correct <dependency> to add in the pom.xml file in order to have those two jar in a Maven configuration?

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the data you are returning, to the browser is not well formed JSON. Then I would remove the attribute "produces" from your Controller, and leave the Spring Jackson transformer to create the json entities.

Change your code to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/hourConsumption", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<HourConsumption> getHoursConsumptions(@RequestBody String day, HttpSession session, Model model) {
    // do something ....
    Household household = (Household)session.getAttribute("household");
    List<HourConsumption> consumptions = this.mrs.getHoursConsumption(household.getSmart_meter().getOid(), day);
    // do something 

    if(consumptions == null) //check if what get back from something is not null
        return null;
    else
        return consumptions; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google's gson (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) to send Json format String to the page.

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/hourConsumption", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getHoursConsumptions(@RequestBody String day, HttpSession session, Model model) {
    String jsonFormatData = "";
    // do something ....
    Household household = (Household)session.getAttribute("household");
    List<HourConsumption> consumptions = this.mrs.getHoursConsumption(household.getSmart_meter().getOid(), day);
    // do something 


    // **Using Gson**
    // You can include this in your bean definition and autowire it
    // and use the singleton created by Spring.
    // For this example I am instantiating Gson myself
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 

    jsonFormatData = gson.toJson(consumptions);

    return jsonFormatData; 
}
```